# Bootstrap-based but accessible template (WCAG 2.0 compliant)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, accessibility, wcag2.0

I am building an admin style, data-driven, internal business application (as opposed to a public facing website). I'd like to use a Bootstrap based template (even considering for-purchase templates from a Bootstrap marketplace or something), but the key requirement is that the site must be accessible (WCAG 2.0 AA compliant).

I know Bootstrap has had some accessibility issues (some colors, some javascript, etc.), but I also know that a lot of that has been getting better as newer versions were getting released. Bootstrap documentation itself offers only a [small section on Accessibility](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#accessibility) and no mention of WCAG 2.0. Does anyone know what the latest status is for accessibility and Bootstrap (ver 3.3.7 at the moment)?

I've also come across [Accessible+](http://www.accessible-template.com/index.html), which is a Bootstrap-based template, but I'm not sure whether the design fits well for the application I'm building, as it seems more public-facing (product/sales based). But it might work.

Alternatively, does anyone have any other Bootstrap based templates to recommend (free or not) which would work well for my need here, while also being very accessible?

Answer (score 3):

I develop and maintain custom bootstrap websites that emphasize WCAG 2.0 AA compliance, but I'm looking for a good Bootstrap based template from which I can develop smaller projects without investing the time for a custom project.

One thing I'm noticing is that the few templates and themes out there advertising as WCAG 2.0 AA / 508 Compliant are NOT actually compliant, including Accessible+. Using the online WebAIM tool on their template it's registering 8 WCAG 2.0 AA coding errors, 16 alerts, and 4 contrast errors on the front page.

The WebAIM online tool is just a starting point, even getting zero errors on the tool does not make a site "compliant" there is no such thing as a "compliant" website ... the criteria is subjective. There are less and compliant and more compliant sites.

Validating with the WebAIM tool does definitely make a site more compliant. To get any sort of certification that a site is compliant actual lab testing by individuals with disabilities is required. Even then, a site can get a certification from the third party that does the testing, there is no universal compliance stamp that the Dept of Justice would refer to if a complaint was filed for a site.

Another thing I've found is that one needs to be careful about what third party to use for a certification of a site. Some are very expensive and do not necessarily have much credibility. The non-profit WebAIM program at Utah State University is one of the most credible and reasonably priced. Their site also offers some of the best overall information about web accessorily and compliance. Note, I have no affiliation whatsoever with that organization other than attending training there.

Answer (score 2):

I'm in the same situation. I'm not sure about how the accesibility of Bootstrap has been improved since the 3.1.1. version.

I also saw the Accessible+ template, but it has been not updated since January, and I'm not sure if can fit what I need, so paying for it will be my last option.

These were my two main options:

- Assets CMS GOV Framework. Its a modification of Bootstrap 3.1.1 with accesibility improvements to acomplish with the section 508 compliance (kind of USA govern alternative to WCGA 2.0, but a little less restrictive than WCGA AA). You can find it here http://assets.cms.gov/resources/framework/3.4.1/Pages/ the problem is that the package is just a bunch of folders with different scripts, styles, etc and I don't know where to start. I took a look to a previous version of the framework http://assets.cms.gov/resources/framework/2.0/Pages/ which was based on Bootstrap 2 and those files seems more like the kind of content I was expecting to find when I download it. So... after a couple of hours thinking if all those folders in the package wehere modificated, or where the originals and how to start, I declined about it... Maybe you can see it more clear.
- The other option, which I'm starting to use, is the current Bootstrap version, with the Paypal Bootstrap plugin for accesibility https://github.com/paypal/bootstrap-accessibility-plugin. This seems more clear for me to figure out how to use, but is from 2 years ago and I don't have too much hope about it.

Anyway... both options are from a couple of years ago. I spent two days searching for anything else but seems that nobody cares a lot about accessibility nowadays. Several changes in accesibility have been implemented on Bootstrap since 3.1.1 but I think still can be far from be ready for a WCAG 2.0 AA.

In Bootstrap 4 beta seems to be more accesibillity improvements, but I don't know if they are enough to accomplish the WCAG 2.0 AA standards.

It will be good to know if you find something interesting!!

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience. I've decided to move forward with Accessible+ template, so we'll see how it plays out.

Comment: On the topic of Bootstrap 4, I wrote a thing that might help meet WCAG 2.0 AA: https://github.com/oaf-project/oaf-bootstrap-4

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I am the author of [Accessible+ accessible bootstrap template](http://www.accessible-template.com/) as linked here by the question opener.

Accessible+ is in fact based on [ASSETS](http://assets.cms.gov/resources/framework/3.4.1/Pages/#) which is based on [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).
I developed it because there were no Bootstrap accessible options available.

The main purpose was a regular template for "non-admin" websites.
Since I did not get overwhelming requests for doing an Admin template version, I never took the time to design one. But - I might in the future.

In any case, I can offer personal customization, even if you ask me to just make you a general "skeleton" for admin side.

Thanks for choosing to buy the template, I know it doesn't suit your needs 100% and I hope you succeed in converting it the way you need.

Comment: thanks for responding here. I like how much accessibility is built into the Accessible+ template so far. I'm still working my way through it (been busy with other aspects of the project), but I really appreciate your prompt communication and assistance. That alone makes Accessible+ a good choice for consideration.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching as well in the past for an accessible Bootstrap 4 template but found nothing. The ones I found failed in most accessibility tests.

Recently though, I searched again and found the "[Labinator A11y-Bootstrap](https://labinator.com/wordpress-marketplace/accessible-html-templates/lab/)" template. It is basically an accessible Bootstrap 4 premium template that satisfies the WCAG 2.1 Level AAA guidelines. It also comes with an accessibility toolbar.

If you need though a free template and have good coding knowledge, then any modern Bootstrap 4 template can be made accessible with proper expertise in web development and accessibility. You can start by reading the official accessibility page of Bootstrap at (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/accessibility/) then familiarize yourself with the WCAG 2.1 Level AA/AAA guidelines. There are some helpful checklists for those online, especially at the official website of WCAG.

Thereafter, you have to test your template with several web accessibility tools and verify the results manually. Two good tools are [AChecker.ca](https://achecker.ca/checker/index.php) and [wave.webaim.org](https://wave.webaim.org/). Please note that all current web accessibility tools are not perfectly accurate - take them with a grain of salt. They can serve as a good pointer in the right direction rather than an ultimate guide.

It is good to note as well that Bootstrap 4+ is much better in terms of accessibility than Bootstrap 3+. As a full-time web developer working in the field, I would never pick Bootstrap 3+ or any template based on it when we have the modern Bootstrap 4.

I hope that helps!